Behaviour of heat exchanger with lowering température input or flow rate
I know the characteristics of an heat exchanger (inlet, outlet, power). I'd like to know its performance if I reduce the inlet temperature of the hot fluid or its flow rate.
My idea is to calculate the logarithmic temperature difference (DTln) and estimate AU coefficient (the product of exchange area and exchange coefficient) by Power = AU*DTln. Therefore, i have the AU for nominal (design) operation.
If I change the “hot” inlet temperature and consider the same temperature difference, I'll get a new DTln and I'll be able (assuming constant AU) to know the new exchanged power.
Is this correct?
However, how can I determine the impact of the flow rate on the power exchanged, since AU can no longer be considered constant?
Thank you for your help.
